# Input textbox onchange is not firing when data is assigned to input textbox

Tags: html, textbox, onchange

This is my HTML page

```
<script>
function set()
{
document.getElementById("txt").value++;
}
</script>
<input id="txt" type="text" onchange="javascript:alert('txt changed');" value="0">
<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="set()" value="Set Data"/>
```

When I press the button, the text box value is changing, and the onchange event is not firing,
but when I enter value manually in the textbox, it is firing the onchange.

All I want is to call a JavaScript function when data is changed in the textbox when a button is clicked.

Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can fire onchange from code using `document.getElementById("txt").onchange();` after the changing the value through code

**UPDATE**

change your set function to take the id of the text box

```
function set(textboxid)
{
    var tb = document.getElementById(textboxid);
    tb.value++;
    tb.onchange();
}
```

Comment: thats a quick reply, but my problem is like i have 5-6 textboxes with separate buttons for each. in that case i have to call this in each and every button click. any other alternatives

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a browser bug. With firebug I have logged all events in input. ANY events is triggered when you change value with function set();

I've tested in firefox.

---

Note: if it isn't a bug, at least is a wrong definition about how events works.