# Fire onchange event for TextBox when readonly is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have some functionality on change of a textbox which is readonly. 
But when I am trying to update the textbox using javascript, the change event is not firing for the textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[id$=_txtTest]').bind("change", function () {
                alert("test");
            });
                        });
        function ChangeText() {
            $('input[id$=_txtTest]').val('hello');
         }
    </script>
```

I am calling ChangeText method on click of a button. But it is not firing the textchange event for the textbox.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600680/input-textbox-onchange-is-not-firing-when-data-is-assigned-to-input-textbox?rq=1

Comment: Also duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672505/why-does-the-jquery-change-event-not-trigger-when-i-set-the-value-of-a-select-us

Comment: You have readonly set to true on the input box? Does the value actually change to 'hello' when you call ChangeText?

Comment: Yes, it is changed to hello, but no event is fired

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you have to do this way: http://jsfiddle.net/kmvSV/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('input[id$=_txtTest]').bind("change", function () {
     alert($(this).val());
   });
   $('button').bind("click", function () {
     $('input[id$=_txtTest]').val('hello').trigger('change');
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

The change event is triggered by real user events only, not javascript actions.

You may trigger the change event, like so:

```
$('input[id$=_txtTest]').val('hello').change();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
function setValueOfTextBox()
{
    var myElement = document.getElementById("textboxid");
    myElement.value = "hello";
    //following code fire change event for you text box
    if (myElement.onchange) 
         myElement.onchange();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for some security reason, the events are not fired.
But you can achieve this by triggering the specific event on that element.
E.g. `$('input[id$=_txtTest]').trigger('change');`

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

### `onkeypress` event *or* one of the [several other events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event):

Since the read-only field doesn't really change; the `onChange` event doesn't
trigger on it.  However; there are [several other events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) that you can listen to.

Here's a short demo:

```css
input {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 2px darkblue solid;
}
```

```html
<script>
function sayHi(evt) {

  alert('Are you tyring to edit a read-only? Click OK for details.')
  alert(JSON.stringify({
    keyCode: evt.keyCode, 
    charCode: evt.charCode, 
    altKey:evt.altKey, 
    ctrlKey: evt.ctrlKey, 
    shiftKey: 
    evt.shiftKey
  }), null, 2);
}
</script>



<input onkeypress="sayHi(event);" readonly placeholder="A readonly field..." />
```