# Jquery onchange does not trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('#selectclassid').trigger("change");
    $('#selectclassid').on('change', function() {
});
```

I have this format for my `onchange` manual trigger of on change but the problem is it is not firing. I am wondering because this is the format I see in tutorials. Could there be anything wrong in the format of on change. I am hoping that it will fire on change when the page is loaded. By the way this select option is in a div that is hidden on load.But will show on button click if this event is related to the problem. Any idea is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm, you seem to be triggering the event *before* you attach it - try it the other way around

```
 $('#selectclassid').on('change', function() {
     console.log("fired")
 });

 $('#selectclassid').trigger("change");
```

Comment: i have a question when my input is readonly even if the pattern is like this the onchange is not firing any idea why?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332972/fire-onchange-event-for-textbox-when-readonly-is-true) - Try googling some questions first - Most of the time it's faster for you to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/ce5rg9mt/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {




$("#selectclassid").on('change', function() {
    alert('The option with value ' + $(this).val());
});


     $( "#selectclassid" ).trigger( "change" );

});
```

Answer (score -2):

Wrap your code inside of the callback function like so:

```
$('#selectclassid').on('change', function(){
    //code here
});
```

And then call the trigger afterwards:

```
$('#selectclassid').trigger('change');
```